# NativeScript Angular RadDataForm with groups inside GridLayout does not expand to show fields on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, layout, nativescript

I have this XML in an Angular NativeScript (6.3.0) component and the form group expands and shrinks correctly on Android when the group title is tapped.

On iOS, the group does not expand if GridLayout rows="auto" is used, and does not shrink if rows="*" is used.

```
<GridLayout rows="auto">
    <RadDataForm row="0" [source]="address">
        <TKPropertyGroup tkDataFormGroups collapsible="true" name="Edit this address" collapsed="true">
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="address" hintText="address" index="0">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="address2" index="1">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="city" index="2">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="state" index="3">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="postcode" index="4">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
            <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="country" index="5">
                <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
        </TKPropertyGroup>
    </RadDataForm>
</GridLayout>
```

Has anybody else had this problem, or am I missing some markup to make it work as I think it should?

Comment: Why you need a GridLayout with only one row? If you are intended to stack items where RadDataForm is one among the items, you may probably try StackLayout.

Comment: I've removed the other rows for simplicity of the example code, but I have also read posts that indicate RadDataForm does not work inside a StackLayout.  Even without other rows, it still demonstrates the problem on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may force relayout on RadDataForm upon expanding view.

```
<RadDataForm row="0" [source]="address"
    (groupExpanded)="onGroupExpanded($event)">


onGroupExpanded(event) {
    event.object.requestLayout();
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=RFMQWv)

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, works perfectly and it also works when using the same code in the groupCollapsed event.